# How would a rebel group best utilise ww2 era planes/equipment against a modern state/dictatorship?

Tags: internal-consistency, warfare, weapons

For context: Modern United States, UK and several other countries have been taken over by a totalitarian dictatorship plotting to revive a Lovecraftian god(This happens later, does not affect this question), and a devoted resistance has risen to defeat them.
This has gone... poorly, as the cult-dictatorship, the Caliphate of the Yellow King, has access to the best military equipment of their controlled nations, a host of dedicated cultist-soldiers, pilots, and even mutated super-soldiers, but again, no bearing to the plot.
In their adventures, the main characters have discovered the locations of several secret, underground military warehouses below the surface of the US, packed to the brim with surplus planes, tanks, AA and the like from WW2 and Early Korea, packed below ground by a paranoid cold-war government in the case of soviet attack.

Thus arises my question;
How best would a non-state force defeat a modern state with obsolete ww2 equipment?
I was thinking they would have maybe

- 150-200 each; B-17 Bombers, m26 Pershing, Vought f4u Corsair
- 300 each; p-51 mustang, p-39 Aerocobra, M4 Sherman
- 400 each; AA guns, M3 Scout Car

Lets say they also have enough bombs/shells to make supply a non-concern, and that they are in perfect working condition, having been refurbished pre-storage, and they have found plenty enough crew members and pilots in soldiers who escaped in time.

The bad guys use the US armed forces equipment, for the sake of simplicity(And because the story mostly takes place in mainland US), so f-35's, black hawks, M1 Abrams, that kind of thing.

Anyways, how best do our plucky rebels utilise their newfound, obsolete attack force against the modern military-industrial complex?

I was thinking use of fighter planes on sneak attacks against isolated attack helicopters from behind, or using tanks as stationary turrets against convoys in the Appalachias, I have no delusions about the outcome of a p-51 against a jet.

Anyways, is this a remotely realistic idea, or have I been playing too many computer games?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. It sounds like you are asking us to write your plot for you, while we prefer to focus on the rules of your world. Please read the [help] to better understand our scope.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to sell all of this magically preserved equipment to museums to generate working capital, then buy up modern small arms and some decent off-road vehicles.

Comment: @L.Dutch Sorry, I might have phrased my question wrong. I was just meaning to ask the most effective(Or least self-destructive) ways obsolete equipment could theoretically be used against modern tanks and jets.

Comment: It looks like your world is built and you're asking how a group of individuals in your world will respond to a situation you've constructed. This is much more of a question about plot/story, and isn't a good fit for this site.

Comment: The rubber gaskets, plastic, etc. on these vehicles will have naturally decomposed and the high explosives will have also decomposed over time to become dangerously unstable.  Neither the vehicles nor the munitions will be usable.

Comment: Sell it on Ebay. "80%" of a single B17 is 9M. P51s go for about 4M. That's over a billion dollars in P51s alone. *How would a rebel group best utilize* billions of dollars? quietly buy all the lithium mines in the world. *How best would a non-state force defeat a modern state?* Terrorism. Or if you have a flag, it's called guerrilla warfare: "a warfare of harassment through surprise." - *'least self-destructive'* needs to be in the question; answer is kamikaze. Same answer to the Q of, how *were* WWII era planes 'best' used.

Comment: War is always a political activity more than military. So, you have to use the military force for the most political good. That means using their actions to keep the rebels together (news and propaganda) and look at how the dictator could lose control by overreacting to the situation. Every dictator has weak points, use them. His own forces can be turned against him.

Answer (score 4):

Sabotage, I believe.

You don't really need a world dictatorship to see how rebels fight against modern armies, there are plenty of examples around the world right now (unfortunately).

And from them, you can learn a lot about how you can fight against modern equipment with retrograde equipment: most of the time, you don't.

Every military has advantages and disadvantages, and your army, and thus, your generals, must analyse the situation accordingly.

But I'm getting ahead of myself, normally what rebels and revolutionary armies do is through sabotage on infrastructure, logistics and politics in order to destabilize the current government in order to gain an advantage (on the battlefield, in the political field etc), and/or just straight up popular uprising.

For that, you need a good coordination by your group, but your enemies will do the same sabotages against you or even sabotaging themselves in order to criminalise your group.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst I love the idea of plucky rebels finding lost arms caches and turning them against their oppressors, in this case most of the equipment is essentially useless.  (But keep reading for the Good News...)

The pace of technological advance was so great during WWII, that by the end of it, most of the equipment used to fight it was already obsolete.

Many of the technologies developed during the war were disruptive - computing, radar, jet power, rocketry.  They enabled capabilities far beyond anything that existed in 1944.

The Cold War only maintained the investments made in military technology sustaining the rate of advance to some extent.

The result is that this old equipment is totally out classed.  A mere M72 LAW is capable of destroying an M4 Sherman for the budget price of around $2000, so your tanks don't even offer protection against *infantry* - let alone the government's armour.  (An M1 Abrahams incidentally would be able to hit an M4 from 2km away, while moving.  The Sherman in contrast has to stop to shoot, and it is doubtful its medium velocity 75mm would do more than scratch the Abraham's paint from 20 metres).

The aircraft would be illuminated by targeting radars and shot down by missiles from beyond visual range.  The fighters might do some good in a close air support role, but their pilots would have very short lifespans even then.  (Look at losses of far more survivable A10s in the latter phases of Desert Storm when the doctrine switched from engaging at range with missiles to close engagement with the gun - and the Iraqi's had roughly 1970's and 80's level tech, not 2000's).

The point of asymmetric warfare as the weaker power is to not fight the enemy head on where they are strongest.  (Heck, that's nearly always the point!)

### Stuff You Can Use

Now, we have hand waved that somehow all the stockpiled munitions are still good...

That makes for an awful lot of IEDs - IF you can somehow draw the government forces out to where you can use them.

You also have a lot of M2 Brownings there - its a timeless classic that still hasn't gone out of fashion.  Design a concealable mounting for pickups and use hit and run tactics.

In a similar vein, you haven't mentioned specific artillery, but the 105mm M101 Howitzer would still be highly effective if mounted concealed on a truck.  You might even be able to mount an entire battery on a couple of semis.  You wouldn't have much ammunition, but you intend to shoot and scoot.

Comment: As you wrote, range is the real killer here. The modern equipment is in kill range at a distance more than 10 times where the WWII stuff could even see the modern ones. There never would be any direct engagement, the modern army units would take down the WWII units before they ever notice where the enemy is.

Answer (score 1):

**Appear where you are not expected.**

http://classics.mit.edu/Tzu/artwar.html

> 21. If he is secure at all points, be prepared for him. If he is in superior strength, evade him.
> 22. If your opponent is of choleric temper, seek to irritate him. Pretend to be weak, that he may grow arrogant.
> 23. If he is taking his ease, give him no rest. If his forces are united, separate them.
> 24. Attack him where he is unprepared, appear where you are not expected.

Your rebels will lose a conventional fight.  In your story they will take the cultists on in a conventional fight, first irritating the cultists, then pretending to be weak.  They don't need to pretend very hard.  The rebels will be crushed.

Really that is just a diversion carried out by brave martyrs.  Your actual attack is on the Pit of the Shoggoths which is the spiritual epicenter of the Yellow King.  It is defended but not as much as it should have been, because the irritated cultists wanted to make an example of the rebels so redeployed forces to crush them completely.

This way in the Battle of the Pit you can have your WW2 armed forces take on a much outnumbered modern force and win.  Then the WW2 armed forces take on Lovecraftian monsters that shamble out of the Pit!  I like the idea that some of the surviving cultists change their thinking when the monsters come out and so it is all the humans vs all the monsters.

Answer (score 1):

**Check out North Korea!**

This seems remarkably similar as North Korea agaibst South Korea. The North has an impressive arsenal, though very old. I'm not an expert, but I've read that they can still be dangerous in their first wave. They can do an incredible amount of damage by simply grabbing as much bombs and rockets as they can, then fly towards their targets and bomb the hell out of them. Most of them will be destroyed before they can return, but the damage is still substantial. They don't have (many) smart weapons though, so still use the military doctrine of carpet bombing  and the like to make sure you hit and destroy the target.

Apply this to your rebels. They need to check for the most effective targets. Although you might think military and factories, the amount of military and factory targets is likely too big. What will be better is destroying leadership and symbols. Strike down enough of their leaders and symbols and they will probably get disheartened instead of fueled by rage. Even if they get more angry and deal a huge blow to the rebels, you might still sort of win. A dictatorship can easily fall apart if power vacuums form. If whole layers of leadership are gone, the people trying to succeed them might fight and devide the whole country. In addition, with many symbols and leaders gone many people will lose faith. They believed in a few people and don't know the rest. In this moment of crisis it can be easy to convince them for the rebels side, though it should look different from the rebels themselves as they will be angry at that particular party.

The way to do this is simple. It seems that much of the equipment is in the country. That means if you suddenly take to the sky, there will be a lot of confusion. Questions where they come from, if they are friendly and if they are errors will plague them. Depending on distance and how many you send it might take too long for them to react adequately and get their leaders to safety/respond with defences.

With rebels embedded in the system you can also strike when most of the leaders are more vulnerable. At a rally for example, where they can't get to a shelter in time. You then bomb the place and strike down any convoys or helicopters that fly off. Try to do this when most  leaders are together for ease. You might also do it during parades and such where they pull out the big rockets for extra effect. You do have more military might around it, but with so much happening it can be easy to overlook or misunderstand an attack. If you simply have so much that it's likely you'll get through anyway, you basically won that part of the battle.

It's never a surefire way to destroy them. Yet I think it's the biggest military blow you can deal. All other military targets are more likely to unite and empower the dictatorship.

Still as rebels it can be better not to show too much strength. Unless you can get a sizable part if the country behind you, you run the risk of getting people to be against you. They will see it as an attack on their country and way of life instead of a liberating move. Much like the people from North Korea will likely respond incredibly aggressive against any attack, inside or outside.

Comment: The reason the NK military would be dangerous is that they could destroy the city of Seoul and probably cause millions of civilian casualties. If one where to ignore that aspect, a single US carrier fleet should be enough to defeat the NK army without suffering any significant losses.

Comment: @quarague Exactly.   The amount of artillery currently in place and able to fire on Seoul with *very* short notice is quite frightening.

Comment: @quarague agreed. This is much like the proposed scenario. If the dictatorship knows the places and can strike first the rebels stand no chance. The plot says the cashes are hidden, suggesting they have first strike capability. I'm also assuming they have handy runways available. Only the planes are really useful in my opinion. Anything else attracts too much attention while having too low speed and destructive power. A host of planes is detected quickly, but their speed and destructive power can give them a good chance to strike before defences are activated, or that not enough are downed.

Comment: The point is the rebels could probably wipe out a city of civilians but they couldn't really do anything againt a modern army. To overthrow an evil dictator that isn't very helpful.

Comment: @quarague agreed. That is why you use that much firepower to surprise the leadership and kill as much of them as possible. Then hope the political upheaval will allow the dictatorship to implode. Otherwise your suggestion is that no ww2 era weapons are useful, which should be an answer and not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

How best would a non-state force defeat a modern state with obsolete ww2 equipment?  I would start by looking at the [most recent example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_in_Afghanistan_(2001%E2%80%932021)).  Really, the WW2 equipment is a nonfactor.  Either your rebel group can win the hearts and minds of the populace and launch a general insurgency, or they can't.

You mention that the regime has "a host of dedicated cultist-soldiers, pilots, and even mutated super-soldiers".  If these true believers make up a majority of the armed forces (and possibly the population at large), then the rebel cause is hopeless.  If they're only used in a more limited fashion (such as an elite special forces group or in supervisory roles), then the goal of the rebels should be to encourage defection and insurrection.

As far as the best way to utilize the WW2 material specifically, I would say to use it sparingly but publicly.  You want to bring enough force to bear that the local police is totally outgunned to force them to deploy their military domestically.  Furthermore, make sure these confrontations are in places where the government's reprisals are sure to cause civilian casualties.  Set up in hospitals, churches, and apartment complexes, and then dig in hard enough to make them bomb you out.  The point of only using a little bit of you material at a time is to ensure that you can do this repeatedly, fanning the flames of hatred over years or decades.